# Как вывести значение из input number через запятую?

Tags: php, input

У меня есть input number

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="0.001" name="data[contribution][]">
```

как мне ввести его значение чрез запятую, к примеру (125,365)

Сейчас выводится так `<?=$data['contribution']?>` и соответственно значение через точку (125.365)

Я ничего не смыслю в PHP, помогите с данным вопросом

Answer (score 1):

В php есть функция для таких задач: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php
Вот для вашей задачи пример из мануала:

```
$number = 1234.56;
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="0.001" name="number">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['number'])){
    $number = str_ireplace('.',',',$_POST['number']);
    echo $number;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-ireplace.php